# Понимание алгоритма Куна

Tags: алгоритм, рекурсия, графы

Понадобилось составить описание алгоритма Куна. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, не ошибся ли я в понимании данного алгоритма.

Поочередно будем запускать обход в глубину из вершин левой доли, еще не насыщенных паросочетанием M. Таким образом, из каждой такой вершины будем пытаться построить M-чередующуюся цепь. Как только найдется увеличивающий относительно M путь, построим новое паросочетание из ребер цепи, не входящих в M.

В массив visitedKuhn записываются значения, отражающие «посещенность» вершин левой доли. Это нужно, чтобы обход в глубину не заходил дважды в одну вершину.

Массивы matchingLeft и matchingRight характеризуют текущее паросочетание.
Каждая ячейка массива matchingLeft[v]=i  содержит индекс вершины правой доли, с которой соединяется ребром соответствующая вершина левой доли с индексом v. Значение i=-1 говорит об отсутствии выбранного ребра, идущего из v в i.

В теле функции просматриваются все ребра, исходящие из вершины v, затем проверяется следующее:

- ведет ли ребро в ненасыщенную вершину правой доли i
- если эта вершина насыщена, можно ли построить увеличивающую цепь из соответствующей вершины matchingRight[i] (которая находится в левой доле).

Если выполняется одно из условий, мы можем утверждать, что нашли увеличивающую цепь. Тогда перенаправим ребро, инцидентное i, в вершину v, а затем вернем в основную программу результат true.

```
bool dfs_kuhn(int v)
{
  if(visitedKuhn[v]) return false; 
  visitedKuhn[v]=true;
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    if(matrix[v][i].weight==0 && (matchingRight[i]==-1 || dfs_kuhn(matchingRight[i])))
    {
      matchingLeft[v]=i;
      matchingRight[i]=v;
      return true;
    }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описание, похоже, верное.

В коде неясно, что за `N` в цикле - здесь же должно быть количество ребер из вершины, т.е. свойство `v`, а не всего графа.

Сравните с [e-maxx](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/kuhn_matching) - может, какие тонкости ещё есть.

Comment: N - это число вершин левой доли (и оно равно числу вершин правой доли)

Comment: Перефразировал часть текста так: Просматриваем все ребра, исходящие из вершины v, и проверяем, не охвачена ли вершина правой доли i паросочетанием. Если она еще не насыщена, то мы нашли увеличивающую цепь. Иначе пробуем построить такую цепь из соответствующей вершины левой доли  matchingRight[i]. Если попытка успешна, можно, как и в первом случае, выполнить чередование (отметить ребро, соединяющее вершины i и v), а затем вернуть значение «истина».

Comment: А, т.е. проверка `matrix[v][i].weight==0` нужна была для отбора ребёр

Comment: Стоит ли по поводу соединения вершин i и v уточнить, что речь о последнем вызванном экземпляре функции? А то как то не очень понятно выходит...

Comment: P.S. Да, отбор ребер нужен, т.к. это часть задачи о назначениях

Comment: Если граф задан списками смежности, то смежные рёбра перечислить легче, а у вас, похоже, матрица. Стоит упомянуть тогда, к чему относится weight

Comment: Нет, про последний вызов не нужно - это естественно для локальных переменных при рекурсии

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.

Comment: да, у меня матрица, явно разбивающая граф на две доли

Comment: Надеюсь, ничего важного я не упустил

Comment: @Maxim Voloshin Для проверки нужно найти смышлёного студента и заставить реализовать по этому описанию ;)

Comment: P.S. Не подскажете, как модифицировать алгоритм Куна для Венгерского алгоритма (чтобы именно обновлять паросочетание, а не строить каждый раз новое)?